# Is this a library or has been added manullay?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webrtc

I am studying webrtc while watching some code I found this. I am confused about it how to tell me about this what is this. Is this a library or some thing done own self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That is your librabay file of "**WebRtc**" or you can say "Module Dependency", it's autometically included
>   when you browse a project, so in your project you can use
>   functionality of "**WebRtc**" by using this libraruy. 
>   There are two ways to add dependency in project:

- Add Dependency in to your buile.gradle file
- Add Module Dependelcy like rightn now you added into your project.

> If you want to Add/Remove this from your project then follow below
>   steps:

1. Open "File"
2. Click on "Project Structure"
3. Click on Module -- > app
4. Click on above last menu "Dependencies"
5. CLick on Plus Icon to Add Dependency
6. If you want to remove dependency then select dependency from left
   "Modules" section , select dependency and click above "Minus" sign
   button.

Hope this may helps you.

Comment: this was very helpful don;t delete it. It will help the new persons in future.

Comment: Happy to help you @ZeeshanAli

Comment: I have one more question stackoverflow banned me to post question. Why? And is there any way to open it again?

Comment: Which question may be your question have less code and no more clearity may be that's why communuty deleted your question, please check guideline how to post a good question on stackoverflow : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask